# Dreamfactory: IBM DB2 connection

Tags: db2

I downloaded what I believe to be the latest copy of Dreamfactory for Windows from Bitnami bitnami-dreamfactory-1.8.2-0-windows-installer.exe.  I would like to connect to an IBM DB2 remote database.  In using the Admin Console I don't see an option in the SQL Vendor dropdown for IBM DB2.  Did I miss a configuration step?  If not, what do I need to do to configure IBM DB2 as a Remote SQL DB?  I can't seem to find a reference in the documentation for how to do this.

Update
I just installed the Bitnami Ubuntu vmware appliance and it has a DB2 dropdown.  Therefore, there is a flaw in the Windows 1.8.2 self installer.

Answer (score 0):

With a quick test of the windows installer, we did confirm the DB2 value is in the dropdown menu. Please try to refresh the window frame or clear browser cache to see if that helps.

Also, the Bitnami package released for 1.8.2 currently doesn't have the db2 driver installed by default. We are working on getting another build that has better default setup. In the mean time, this [link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.php.doc/doc/t0023667.html) has the Windows instructions. I will try to get a more detailed instruction set for Windows.

Comment: Excellent!  1) It was a cache problem. 2) That link is exactly what I needed. 3) Also, it is good to know that the package does not have DB2 setup.  Thanks.